# Background thread Interact with UI

Tags: java, android

I am using Eclipse and programming for android.  Can an AsyncThread interact with the UI, I have this code in my background thread and it is causing an exception to be thrown:

```
if (pressTime == 0){
    displayTime.setText("You missed your ring");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?! And also, what is your `displayTime`, where was it declared, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Handler`. Just create it in the UI Thread, then post a call to it from your async thread.

For example, if you are using an `AsyncTask`, just add the following global variable:

```
Handler mHandler;
```

Next, in your task's constructor, or `onPreExecute` method, add the following line:

```
mHandler = new Handler();
```

Finally, as long as the above line was called on the *UI Thread*, you can execute code on said Thread in your `doInBackground` method using the following:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (pressTime == 0)
            displayTime.setText("You missed your ring");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Only the thread that actually has created the view (tipically the UI Thread) can modify the view. You have to post on the UI Thread queue the modify you want to brought to the the UI. Tipically, in your context is the activity, this is achieved with `runOnUiThread`. Otherwise you can use and `Handler`.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) the doc for runOnUiThread. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for Handler.